# Ruby: specify has_many :through association when several has_many :through associations are given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

i have a simple data set-up with a model for Users and a model for Tasks.
Between these two models i have two has_many :through associations: Fellowships and Assignements. In total i want to specify for a task several followers and several assignees.

I now want to display for a specific task all assignees and all followers.
If there would only be one association I simply could do @task.users. As i have two associations i want to specify by which association i want to get all users.

See my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :tasks, through: :assignments

    has_many :fellowships
    has_many :tasks, through: :fellowships
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :users, through: :assignments

    has_many :fellowships
    has_many :users, through: :fellowships
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :task
end

class Fellowship < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :task
end
```

Let's assume i have a task as

```
@task = Task.first
```

I now want to have all assignees and all followers with something like

@assignees = @task.users "over association assignment"

@followers = @task.users "over association followship"

but i don't know how to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can write in following way.

> has_many :assignment_tasks ,through: :assignments ,source: :task
>
> has_many :fellowship_tasks, through: :fellowships, source: :task

Comment: So if i add these assigenment_tasks and fellowship_tasks to my models associations, can i then use `@assignees = @task.assignment_users`  and `@followers = @task.fellowship_users`?

Comment: What about using `assignees` and `followers` instead of assignment_tasks and fellowships_tasks. That way, you can fetch using `@task.followers` and `@task.assignees`.